# SQLite Error with Foreign Key Android

Tags: android, sqlite

im making an app with some SQLite database but It crashes by an SQLite Syntax error (Android Studio Debug Report)

```
CREATE TABLE paneles(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mega_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (mega_id) REFERENCES megas(id), codigobarras INTEGER,nombre TEXT);
```

it says is near codigobarras, but I can't find the error

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `FOREIGN KEY (mega_id) REFERENCES megas(id)` at the end of your `CREATE TABLE`.

In the SQL syntax, column specifications come first and table constraints such as `FOREIGN KEY` after that. No column specifications can follow the table constraints, hence the syntax error.

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html